# what is the best approach to store and fetch files that needs to be processed with a Django

Tags: python, django, distributed

I have a secret sharing app in django that processes a user uploaded file and transforms it into N different shares (or segments). Each segment has to be stored on a remote server (storage servers are within the same domain as the django server). In the download stage, when a user asks for the file, django fetches the segments from the storage servers and combines them to re-create the file and then delivers it to the user.

I'm  new to django and have spent weeks trying to figure out a solution for the storage and fetching part.

The challenge is the timeout that the user might face if the fetching of segments and combining them takes too long.

My question being: considering size of the files often less than 10MB and the possibility of 100 concurrent connection, what kind of approach should I take for the part that django wants to store the segments and fetching them upon users request?

**I'm forced to use local inter-domain storage severs without cloud solutions like AWS or Google App Engine for security reasons.**

Comment: You could try combining them on an asynchronous task, and poll for updates from the client. Trying to run a long task in a synchronous way will give a bad user experience and may lead to timeouts.

Comment: @cdvv7788 you are absolutely right about and for that sake I'm using celery to do the tasks in the background. But what would you propose for segment download and uploads between django server and the storage nodes?